# How to search/replace while including or excluding folded text?

Tags: vim, code-folding

Is there any way to run a command like:

```
:%s/tempdir/temp_dir/g
```

But apply it only to either folded or unfolded code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:folddoopen` and `:folddoclose` do exactly what you want:

```
:folddoopen s/tempdir/temp_dir/g
:folddoclosed s/tempdir/temp_dir/g
```

Reference:

```
:help folding
:help :folddoopen
:help :folddoclosed
```

Comment: Excellent - that's exactly what I needed and somehow couldn't find.